# Reformulating undirected to directed edges for MCF

Tags: graphs, network-flow

As stated in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1002/net.1035), there is a technique to reformulate a multi-commodity flow problem (MCF) with undirected edges to its equivalent version with directed edges.

By quoting them:

> The reformulation involves adding two additional nodes and four
> additional arcs for each undirected arc.

However, just from this sentence I can't figure out the shape of the new graph.
I also have problem to retrieve the original reference describing in detail such transformation.

Can someone explain how to do this? Also, considering that I am working with a minimisation MCF, is there a more efficient transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the reference provided in the paper (exercise on page 689 of the classic book Ahuja et al., 1993). The transformation is just to turn an undirected edge to a directed version. In this case also taking care of capacities and costs. There are many more useful transformations in this book.

For an undirected edge $i$ and $j$, we add two nodes $i'$ and $j'$ and 4 new edges (total of 5 directed edges) with two cycles. Only the edge between $i'$ and $j'$ has a capacity and cost associated with it. The rest have a capacity of $\infty$ and a cost of 0.

It is very clear with a picture:

[image]

Ahuja, R., Magnanti, T., & Orlin, J. (1993). Network flows: theory, algorithms, and applications. PrenticeHall, Upper Saddle River, NJ.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It would be great if you may share other maybe better solutions!

Comment: Here's a link to the reference.
http://yalma.fime.uanl.mx/~roger/work/teaching/class_NetworkFlowProgramming/books/network%20flows-Ahuja.pdf

Comment: Nice that you found a link! This transformation is the appropriate one here. What I meant is that there are other useful ones, see Section 2.4 page 38, depending on what you want to achieve.